# converting an array of matrices (including charachter string) to an expanded matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to do a script for nodal analysis for an arbitrary circuit(much like spice).I want to import data from a text file and create a matrice on which further operations will be based on.
so I've used textscan

```
fid = fopen('text2.txt');
netlist = textscan(fid,'%s%s%d%d%d%d%f');
```

so for an input file like this:

```
R1 R 1 0 3 0 0 
C1 C 1 0 5 0 0 
L1 L 2 1 10 0 0 
R2 R 1 2 1 0 0 
i1 Iac 2 0 1 1 0.523
```

the result wil be this

```
 {5x1 cell}    {5x1 cell}    [5x1 int32]    [5x1 int32]    [5x1 int32]    [5x1 int32]
 [5x1 double]
```

the problem is, now I can't call any individual value from the matrice. So I'm trying to figure out how to recreate the original matrice(if possible) and if that didn't work, could you show me a way to call  individual elements (like for example C in (2,2)?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cell arrays are simply another way to store data. Specifically, cell arrays are needed when each cell contains data of different type or different dimensions (in which case, using a matrix won't work).

To access an individual element in the cell array, you use curly braces (`{}`). After  `textscan` your data is stored as columns, so you first access the i-th column by `C{i}`.

Then you need to think what your cell contains. Column 2 contains strings, so it's another cell array (you can also verify it in the result -- column 2 is described as a `{5x1 cell}`). Therefore, you'll need to use curly braces again. If you want to access the 2nd element in the 2nd column, you will have to write:

```
C{2}{2}
```

**P.S.**
If you were to access the 2nd element in the 3rd column, you'd be using round braces `()` for the second subscript, because the second column is a vector. In such case, the syntax should be:

```
C{3}(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming those output matrices are stored in variables or else in another cell array?

What you could do is to keep the two text array's as cell arrays, you can find out the row for a particular string like this (it's possible I got the arguments of `ismember` reversed):

```
find(ismember(FirstCellArray, "R1") == 1)
```

Then you could combine the numerical arrays into a single matrix. You would have to specify how they are stored here, but lets say they are in separate variables called col1, col2 etc (which obviously they are not, you probably need to use cell2mat but we need to see the structure of the cell matrix housing them) then you can combine them like this:

```
NumberMatrix = [col1, col2, col3 ...];
```

You might need to cast them back to doubles but i doubt it:

```
NumberMatrix = [double(col1), double(col2), double(col3) ...];
```

now if you wanted the 3rd number value of row R1 R you can go

```
index1 = find(ismember(FirstCellArray, "R1") == 1);
index2 = find(ismember(SecondCellArray, "R") == 1);
rowIndex = intersect(index1, index2);
value = NumberMatrix(rowIndex, 3)
```